# angular js config router conflict with foundation accordian

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

here is my situation,I use the accordation of foundation inside angular js app,the accoedation works with href attribure of the anchor tag,but when I click on the anchor tag the router config is fired but the the accordation is not working.
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0yQN06mWpvcra9y19rg?p=preview) I worked with

```
var config = function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {


    $routeProvider.when("#panel1a", {
       templateUrl: "app/components/header/headerTemplate.html",

    });


};

(
        function() { 'use strict';angular.module('loca', ['ngRoute']);
        angular.module('loca').config(config);
    }   
)();
```

Answer (score -1):

add **target="_self"** next to href="blahblah"